# Combining Lines and Boxplots in R

Tags: r, lines, boxplot

i am trying to plot 2 line graphs and add 2 boxplots in the end. i would like the boxplots to stand at the end of the linegraphs. for that i would like to extend my x axis without any labelling and put my boxplots in these 2 empty spaces i want to create.

the x axis is formatted as a date.

```
xrange <- range(xjahredf$datum)
yrange <- range(xjahredf[,(names(xjahredf) != "datum")]) 
maxy <- max(yrange)
miny <- min(yrange)


# set up the plot
plot(xrange, yrange, bty = "l", type="n", xlab="Datum",ylab="werte", xaxt="n" )
axis.Date(side = 1, at=seq(xjahredf[1,1],xjahredf[37,1], length.out=12), format= "%Y-%m" , las=2)
colors <- c("red","blue")
boxplot(xjahredf$x1, axes=FALSE, range=0,  ylim=c(miny,maxy), at=16450, add=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, lwd=0.5, col=colors[1], boxwex = 100)
boxplot(xjahredf$x3, axes=FALSE, range=0,  ylim=c(miny,maxy), at=16500, add=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, lwd=0.5, col=colors[2], boxwex = 100)

for (i in 2:ncol(xjahredf)) {

  lines(xjahredf$datum, xjahredf[,i], type="l", lwd=1.5,
    lty=1, col=colors[i-1])
}
```

xjharedf is my dataframe with 3 columns (datum/x1/x3)

datum is formatted as date (2012-12-1) and then we have some values in x1 and x3. the at=16450 in the boxplot defines the position of the boxplot in the overall plot, but becaues the xaxis is formatted as date it counts dates starting from 1jan of 1970 (or something like that)

when i now run my script i get my 2 glines with the right axis in date format and 2 overlapping boxplots in the end where 1 is out of the frame...

p.s. i am still a noob in r and might lack knowledge on some basic stuff!

Comment: Are you just trying to put several plots on a page, as described here: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: Yes and no. I have played around with the method you refer to but could not produce what I was looking for.

Yes because in general the boxplot is near a position where I want to have it. (allthough id like boxplot to be way closer to the end of my lines)

No because I don´t need the axis on the bplots and rather than just putting my boxplots next to each other and next to my lines I prefer having them in 1 plot area (if that makes sense?) The thing is that the more boxplots I add to my line graphs the more space they take up in comparison to the whole plot area.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

so we did the follwoing and it worked. i am sure though there is an easier way to do this.

we formatted the date column from the df in character and provided a character vector as the labels in the axis function. we made the range of the plot bigger than the area that was covered by the labels which brought us empty space in the end of our graph. all we did then was put the boxplots in the according positions with the at= argument. all thats left now is adding the lines. hope this was of any help.

```
plot(c(0,40), yrange, bty = "l", type="n", xlab="Datum",
 ylab="werte", xaxt="n")
axis(side = 1, at = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36), 
           labels = substr(c("2012-0sub1-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-04-01", "2012-05-01", "2012-06-01", "2012-07-01", "2012-08-01", 
                      "2012-09-01", "2012-10-01", "2012-11-01", "2012-12-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", 
                      "2013-05-01", "2013-06-01", "2013-07-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-09-01", "2013-10-01", "2013-11-01", "2013-12-01", 
                      "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", "2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01", 
                      "2014-09-01", "2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01"),1,7), las=2)
colors <- c("red","blue")
boxplot(xjahredf$x1, axes=FALSE, range=0,  ylim=c(miny,maxy), at=37, add=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, lwd=0.5, col=colors[1], boxwex = 2, alpha = 0.2)
boxplot(xjahredf$x3, axes=FALSE, range=0,  ylim=c(miny,maxy), at=39, add=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, lwd=0.5, col=colors[2], boxwex = 2, alpha = 0.2)
```